# Show Sharepoint Library Ribbon/Tab

Tags: document-library, library, sharepoint-library

We're at trial stage where we would upload all our PDF documents onto Sharepoint.

the issue is, we can only download it one by one. We are trying to download multiple files at once.

All websites & forums say to use IE, and click on the open with explorer on the Library Tab.

I can't locate the library tab anywhere.

Please help.

We are accountants and not IT specialist, so we don't really know any codings.

Is there an easier way to get the Library Tab/Ribbon to show?

Thanks

Comment: could you please share the screen image? are you using SharePoint online(office 365) or sharepoint on prem?

Answer (score 1):

One common scenario for not appearing the LIBRARY tab in the Document Library view is that, you haven't selected any items. If you are not seeing the LIBRARY tab in browser, first select any of the item and after it will show the ribbon menus. Once the library tab appears on the document library view you can choose the **Open with Explorer** option (Of course, it will only work in IE).

You can have a look at it below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are viewing the SharePoint library in the new mode, from the left side of the library's page, you'll find a link on the bottom left called: show in classic view/mode. After clicking that, it will show you the library with the library tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are opening the SharePoint Site in the new mode. If you open it in the classic mode it will show you those tabs.

Click on the gear(wheel) on the right upper corner. select add content. Then scroll down in the left corner it will have tab that says "Return to classic SharePoint". This will show the tabs for page, library.